# Improving Google Cloud Speech-to-Text accuracy

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm working on a project where I need to perform these steps:

1. Record a voice call (`.webm` -file)
2. Split the `webm` -file into chunks with `ffmpeg` and convert the file into `wav`
3. Transcribe the chunks using `SpeechRecognition` -library and Google Cloud API

I've faced problems with the transcription accuracy and wondering if there is something I could do to improve it. At the time I'm splitting the original file into 30s chunks. I thought there might be one problem, that I might be missing words because of splitting so I've tried also with longer chunks under 60s but didn't notice any improve in accuracy.
Reading trough the speechRecognition docs I decided to set `r.energy_threshold = 4000`, I also tried to set the `energy_treshold` dynamically like this:

```
with sr.AudioFile(name) as source:
    r.dynamic_energy_threshold = True
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration = 1)
    audio = r.record(source)
```

I've also tested `en-US` and `en-GB` to see if there's some difference but there isn't as much as I'd want. The program is supposed to work with english language spoken by nordic people. If someone has experience about choosing a right language model for people speaking with accent, please let me know.

This is the `ffmpeg` command is use to split the webm file into chunks: `command = ['ffmpeg', '-i', filename, '-f', 'segment', '-segment_time', '30', parts_dir + outputname + '%09d.wav']`

Is there somethig I could do better? I'm wondering if the quality is not good enough an Google is having hard time because of that?

The main problem is I'm getting bad results (lots of wrong words) from Google and wondering if there is something I could do about it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use Google Speech API directly and transcribe whole files. Split is a bad idea.
2. Use [speech context](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation) feature to improve accuracy.
3. For telephony use specific phone model from Google
4. Use other toolkits which allow to adapt to your audio and vocabulary. Usually for bad audio cases adapted open source toolkit shows much better accuracy than generic Google solution.
5. Share audio files to give better idea about accuracy.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried to run whole files using cloud bucket and it indeed improved the accuracy! On the other hand, the processing time is way too slow for my apps purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Check the sample rate of the .webm & .wav file to see that you are not up/down-sampling the file. I think it is allowed to skip explicitly setting the sample rate of the audio in the request to Google Speech, but I suspect it will give a higher accuracy if you set the correct sample rate manually.

I agree with Nikolay that it is a bad idea to split the audio but if you have to in order for it to work you should try to detect periods of [silence in the file with ffmpeg](http://%20https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silencedetect). You can split the file where there is >2-3s of silence as Google Speech interprets that as end of a sentence so it shouldn't impact your result. If you plan on making a lot of requests it might be good to also try not to split the audio into chunks of, ex: 31s as that will result in 3 * 15s charge from Google Speech instead of 2 if you were to split at 29s instead.